# Program type already present: com.android.volley.BuildConfig

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, android-volley, build.gradle

I have one library project in which i have implemented volley library.

```
api 'com.android.volley:volley:1.1.0'
```

So i can use same library in main application.
But when i try to use in main application and try to build apk then issue is that **Program type already present: com.android.volley.BuildConfig**

But if i exclude volley from library project and comment classes that using volley, doing below line then i am able to build apk.

```
exclude group: "com.android.volley"
```

So how i can resolve this issue?

Comment: Did you managed to solve this? I am facing a similar issue, and I am unable to solve it...

Comment: @Fustigador I was not able to solve as this particular library's jar was in one of the my old library. So solution was to upgrade library or explicitly exclude while compiling.

Answer (score 1):

Try to remove the library from the module and from the project as well and try to implement volley 
`implementation 'com.android.volley:volley:1.0.0'` on build.gradle of both module and project file.

Answer (score 0):

That error generally means you have two dependencies that are both providing the same class, causing a conflict.There could be two copies of Volley 
Like:

implementation 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library:1.0.19'
implementation 'com.android.volley:volley:1.1.0'

You can only use one of these or the other. Make sure your dependencies only pull in one copy of the library.

(Note this not my own answer but found it on 
https://github.com/google/volley/issues/239 which helped me fixing the issue)